# How to check if there is a message in the message queue of joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

how can I check if there is a message in the message queue? for example how can I do something like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var message='<jdoc:include type="message" />'
        if(message!="")
          {
             alert(message);
          }
</script>
```

I am using joomla 2.5. 
Thank you

Comment: The JS you have given as an example looks like it would work if it's in a template, so, I'm not clear what you're asking here...

Comment: OK, so help me out here with some clues... PHP errors? Javascript errors? what is happening?

Comment: It is printing the html on the page and I get a javascript error

Comment: I was wondering if I could get those messages from the queue without getting the html output that causes javascript to break

Comment: So, those are the sorts of things you need to put in the question... that way more people can respond. Let me think about it for a second.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, the problem is really needing to strip the HTML from the `message` variable. Several things to note:

1. Joomla! could be returning multiple messages.
2. Alert are a blocking event for browsers... do you really want to do that?

First up you could place the messages in a `JSON` block by using some basic PHP.

```
<?php
    $jAp = JFactory::getApplication();
    $messagesJSON = json_encode($jAp->getMessageQueue());
?>
```

Then later in your template you could `echo` the messages JSON array into your Javascript similar to your original attempt.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var messageJSON = <?php echo $messagesJSON; ?>
    ... then loop through the JSON block
```

This way you end up with just the text and type of the message and not the particular formatting of the current style/override.

Answer (score 2):

i could not understand your question but you can get msg queue like this

```
$mainframe= JFactory::getApplication();
    $messages = $mainframe->getMessageQueue();
    if (is_array($messages)) {
       echo '<ul id="system-messages">';
       foreach($messages as $msg) {
          echo '<li class="' . $msg['type'] . '">' . $msg['message'] . '</li>';      
       }
       echo '</ul>';
    }
```

Comment: `$mainframe` isn't available in Joomla! 2.5 —> you need to use the application object.

Comment: @cppl - $mainframe exists everywhere, because it's just a variable that is being assigned with JFactory::getApplication();. You can use $mainframe, $app, $foobar, $helloworld, whatever you want as long as you refer to it when instantiating the object. Of course, for the sake of code standards, it's usefull to use something like $app (for application) and then: just use $app = JFactory::getApplication(); $app->getMessageQueue();

Comment: @Mario the original answer from Rakesh didn't have the first line `$mainframe= JFactory::getApplication();`, in Joomla!'s history (i.e. prior to the 1.6->2.5 line) `$mainframe` was a `global` see here - http://docs.joomla.org/Adapting_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_1.6#Legacy_Mode_Removed